# flutter specifying width, height, paddings, margins etc in percentages?

Tags: flutter, responsive, dimensions

Is there a way in flutter which allows the widths, heights, paddings, margins etc being specified in percentages of screen dimensions instead of writing calculations in every widget?

Passing around a provider or extending some base class for this trivial thing is not feeling right.

Answer (score 1):

The only known solution is to use `MediaQuery`. I implemented a helper class that I just call the methods for:

```
class SizeManager {
  var _context;
  double _screenHeight;
  double _screenWidth;

  SizeManager(this._context) {
    _screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(_context).size.height;
    _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(_context).size.width;
  }

  double scaledHeight(double value) {
    return value * _screenHeight / 100;
  }

  double scaledWidth(double value) {
    return value * _screenWidth / 100;
  }
}
```

In every `build()`, just before the `return`, call it like:

```
SizeManager sizeManager = new SizeManager(context);
```

And whenever you want to set margins/padding/size:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: sizeManager.scaledHeight(2.5)), //Gives a 2.5 % height padding
),
```

Comment: So only possible ways are, have all the widgets extend from some SizeManager or create instance of SizeManager in every widget? and every time have to add the calculation?

Isn't there an option where we tell flutter to treat our sizes in percentages?

Comment: Oh, I made a different class for such utility methods and call that class everywhere I need to. Just create a SizeManager at the top of every Widget, initialise it in the build method. After that its literally calling the same thing over and over again.

Comment: And no, unfortunately, flutter does not have a percentage based concept, or even DIPs etc. from what I know. You could have a look at [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)